# How to get the ```Animation``` object of the drawer?

Tags: user-interface, animation, flutter, flutter-animation

i guess the title is pretty straight forward ! what i want is to use the same `Animation<double>` that the drawer use in my code ,
why ? i want to build an animation inside the drawer it self for my project , but if i used a custom `AnimationController` or relied on the `DrawerController.drawerCallback` i wont notice if the user held the drawer in the middle or if the user didn't complete the opening and closing swipe of the drawer.

I'v tried to google it but all i get is the `DrawerController` , no luck,please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share some code which you tried. Would be a good starting point to work out a solution. :)

Comment: unfortunately there is nothing to show here I'm clueless on the drawer animation controller and i'v tried to google it but i couldn't find any thing to start with